# Remove space between each item in dropdown list

Tags: php, html, file, foreach, dropdown

I have two files one PHP file and one txt file. My first goal was to populate the dropdown list with the values in the txt file. Which i managed to do, but when i did that it created a space between each line. What am i doing wrong, and how do i correct this issue?

[image]

**File Name: TestingCombobox.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<body>
         <select class="form-control" style="width:75px;">
           <?php
                $filename = 'list_Things.txt';
                $eachlines = file($filename, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);//create an array
                foreach($eachlines as $lines){
                    echo "<option>{$lines}</option>";
                }
            ?>    
        </select>
<body>
</html>
```

**list_Things.txt**

```
<option value="--"> (--)&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;UNKNOWN</option>
<option value="CA"> (CA)&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;CALIFORNIA</option>
<option value="MX"> (MX)&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;MEXICO</option>
<option value="NV"> (NV)&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;NEVADA</option>
<option value="NC"> (NC)&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;NORTH CAROLINA</option>
<option value="IL"> (IL)&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;ILLINOIS</option>
<option value="NY"> (NY)&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;NEW YORK</option>
<option value="OH"> (OH)&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;OHIO</option>
```

Comment: replace `echo "<option>{$lines}</option>";` with `echo $lines;`

Comment: Homework question ??

Comment: That solved it, and no this is not a homework question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue you are experiencing is that you have a double option that is being read by the browser. if you go to the browser, right click and view source, you should see

View Source:

```
<option><option value="--"> (--)&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;UNKNOWN</option></option>
<option><option value="CA"> (CA)&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;CALIFORNIA</option></option>
<option><option value="MX"> (MX)&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;MEXICO</option></option>
<option><option value="NV"> (NV)&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;NEVADA</option></option>
<option><option value="NC"> (NC)&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;NORTH CAROLINA</option></option>
<option><option value="IL"> (IL)&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;ILLINOIS</option></option>
<option><option value="NY"> (NY)&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;NEW YORK</option></option>
<option><option value="OH"> (OH)&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;OHIO</option></option>
```

change the php code.

File Name: TestingCombobox.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<body>
     <select class="form-control" style="width:75px;">
       <?php
            $filename = 'list_Things.txt';
            $eachlines = file($filename, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);//create an array
            foreach($eachlines as $lines){
                echo $line;
            }
        ?>    
    </select>
<body>
</html>
```